# How is the "verb government" called in Russian?

Tags: грамматика, перевод, глаголы, терминология

As a Russian student, I've learnt that Russian verbs, like in other languages, "govern" certain cases.

For example: **Читать —> что?** (Accusative or Винительный падеж).

After a little search, I found the verb **управлять**, and the noun would be **управление**. Would this be the correct term to refer to this part of speech?

Furthermore, how would I go asking this in Russian?

> What's the *"управление"* for this verb?

Comment: Управл_е_ние would be correct.

Comment: @Quassnoi Ah ops! Typo. :)

Comment: Управление is a "function" or property of verb, not a part of speech.

Comment: @kirilloid Who said it was a part of speech? That "govern" is a verb right there, not a noun.

Comment: Maybe, I understood your phrase _Would this be the correct term to refer to this part of speech?_ incorrectly. Ok, there're verbs in Russian. They have some property called управление. And the word управление is a noun.

Comment: @kirilloid Yes yes... Also other languages work the same way, like German for example. :) But I came to be aware of this only when I started learning Russian some years ago. :P

Comment: Yep, I just found that, when googled "управление" w/o specifying language.

Comment: So is this question about the Russian word for "govern" or is it really about the name of a part-of-speech? Somebody who understands all of this should edit the question to make it clear because it's very unclear now. I think it's the former in which case the question should not talks about p-o-s and the tags [tag:terminology] and [tag:translation] should be added.

Comment: @hippietrail Yeah, I fixed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, *управление* is the correct term.

The question would translate as *Каково управление этого глагола?*

Comment: Can you answer the other part too? If you want to include additional info that could improve the quality of this question, it would be fantastic. :D

Comment: @Alenanno: which part? Yes, управление is a correct term for putting an object into a certain case.

Comment: @Alenanno: I should warn you, however, that AFAIK this term is not included in the school curriculum. So, an average native speaker might have no idea what you're asking. You could ask, like, Какой падеж после себя требует этот глагол? or something similar.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Oh really? You mean it's not used in a school context?

Comment: @Alenanno: I know the term very well, but I am pretty sure we didn't cover it in school. Of course the notion of transitiveness (переходность) of verbs is covered as a grammatical category, but the required case is obvious for native speakers. Incidentally, a lot of German native speakers I spoke to didn't know what Rektion was, which is exactly the same thing

Comment: I suppose, it is included in school program, but ... yes, average native speaker might have no idea about this concept from theoretical point of view.

Comment: @texnic I was actually waiting to see if someone else wanted to post other answers. By the way, don't worry, I'm not new to the SE sites. :P

Comment: @Alenanno I won't :) Thanks for responding.